# Android: context error when calling getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, android-context

I have a database where i store the names of some photos.
At onCreate() method i make a new PointofInterestAdapter:

```
String[] from=new String[] {"name", "address", "favorite", "type", "distance"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.favoriteImage, R.id.icon, R.id.distance};
//SCAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, null, from ,to, 0);   
SCAdapter = new PointOfInterestAdapter(this, R.layout.row_subcategory, null, from ,to, 0);
list.setAdapter(SCAdapter);
```

Here is the code for making the SCAdapter:

```
class PointOfInterestAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    PointOfInterestAdapter(Context ctxt, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(ctxt,layout,c,from,to,flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_subcategory, parent, false);
      PointOfInterestHolder holder=new PointOfInterestHolder(row);
      row.setTag(holder);
      return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        PointOfInterestHolder holder=(PointOfInterestHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, databaseConnector);
    }
}

static class PointOfInterestHolder {
    private TextView name=null;
    private TextView address=null;
    private ImageView icon=null;
    private ImageView favoriteImage=null;
    private TextView distance=null;

    PointOfInterestHolder(View row) {
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
        favoriteImage=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.favoriteImage);
        icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        distance=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DatabaseConnector databaseConnector) {
        name.setText(databaseConnector.getName(c));
        address.setText(databaseConnector.getAddress(c));
        distance.setText(databaseConnector.getDistance(c)+" m");

        //---set the image ---
        String photo_name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("photo_name"));
        int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(photo_name, "drawable",  getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        //Resources res = getResources();
        //Drawable drawable=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
        icon.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));


        //--> set favorite image
        if(databaseConnector.getFavorite(c).equals("yes")) {
            favoriteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_yes);
        }
        else if (databaseConnector.getFavorite(c).equals("no")) {
            favoriteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_no);
        }
    }
}
```

at 
populateForm(Cursor c, DatabaseConnector databaseConnector) 
i try to set the image

The problem is that i get that error message:

**"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper"**

at lines:

int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(photo_name, "drawable",  getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

and here:

icon.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));

How can i solve that problem ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply pass the `context` reference to your `PointOfInterestHolder` class in the `newView()` method and use that. Also, your views have a `Context` that you can get with `view.getContext()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you be more specific please. How can i do that?

Comment: In the `newView` method use: `PointOfInterestHolder holder=new PointOfInterestHolder(row, ctxt);`. Also change the `PointOfInterestHolder` class: `...private Context mContext;

    PointOfInterestHolder(View row, Context context) { mContext = context;...`. Then you could use `mContext` to get the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ Luksprog you will need the activity context which is passed to the constructor of your adapter class.

You have this

```
  private Context mContext; 
  PointOfInterestAdapter(Context ctxt, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(ctxt,layout,c,from,to,flags);
    mContext = ctxt;
}
```

Then use the context

```
 int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(photo_name, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

Note

Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself)

More info @

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: I will avoid to keep a context as reference. This one cause of memory leaks in android. Since he has already lot of views initialized he can use those to retrieve the context

Comment: @blackbelt valid point. could make the adapter an inner class of the activity class in that case right?

Comment: not necessarily. he could use `name.getContext();` for instamnce

Comment: what do you mean with name.getContext();

Comment: @blackbelt how does this work  `LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater()`?. i agree on the point that it is better to avoid keeping long references to activity context.

Answer (score 0):

This is the constructor you defined. I see you are passing context in it as a param. Use it itself
    PointOfInterestAdapter(Context ctxt, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(ctxt,layout,c,from,to,flags);
        }

you have ctxt/Context already in the constructor, Declare a local variable and store this ctxt in that.  like below

```
class PointOfInterestAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

Static Context mCtx; // local context instance
    PointOfInterestAdapter(Context ctxt, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(ctxt,layout,c,from,to,flags);
    mCtx = ctxt; // assigning context instance in local variable
    }
```

......................

now use mCtx where ever you using `getApplicationContext()`